# CSS Property "box-orient" replacement

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following CSS definition:

```
    .foo {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        box-orient: horizontal;
    }
```

NU Validation complains with `CSS: box-orient: Property box-orient doesn't exist.`

According to Mozilla documentation the property was replaced. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient
But it does not say with what.

Anyone knows?

Comment: *nd has been replaced by a newer standard. See flexbox for information about the current standard.* --> it's replaced by the new flexbox properties. You simply need to refer to the new Spec to find what you want

Comment: Yeah, what he said. It says it on the Mozilla page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient

Comment: And you [don't need all those vendor prefixes](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flex-direction

```
 .foo {
   flex-direction: row;
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `row` (for horizontal) only? What's the purpose of  `column` here?

Comment: I was just using that as an example as to what you could put there. Either 
flex-direction: column; 
or
flex-direction: row;